# Help solving for log likelihood

Tags: self-study, likelihood

I need help solving the log-likelihood for the following problem:

[image: Here is the joint probability mass function]

The solution is below:

[image]

I'm curious about the steps to take in the process. I understand that we multiply the entire pmf n times, which gives us the n in the exponent, but I'm curious about where the x-bar and y-bar come from. Also, is this a common joint pmf?

Thanks!

Comment: Please add the [self-study] tag (and read its tag wiki)

Comment: Have you learned anything about differential Calculus?  That's the collection of procedures that is routinely used to solve problems like this, so if it's unfamiliar to you, that would be a great place to start.

Comment: Hi, the original problem didn't have the x and y exponents over the thetas. This is part of the reason I found it confusing. Is this a typo? It was presented as f(x,y,theta1,theta2)=... instead of f(x,y|theta1,theta2).

Comment: Regarding exponents: Probably not a typo, since solving the problem with the exponents leads to the solution you provide.

Answer (score 1):

So, for some PDF and observed datapoints, the likelihood function is simply the product of the PDF for each observed datapoint.

$L(\theta | x) = \prod_{x=1,..,n, y=1,..,n} f(x, y | \theta_1, \theta_2)$

The log likelihood is (you guessed it!) simply the log of the product of the PDF. Now, one property of logs is that log(x*y*z) = log(x) + log(y) + log(z). So, the loglikelihood can be expressed as the sum of log PDF, instead of the product of the PDF.

$$log(L(\theta | x)) = \sum_{x=1,...,n,y=1,...,n} log(f(x, y | \theta_1, \theta_2) $$

Now, we use this same property of logs to rewrite the PDF. I'm going to leave that to you, but you'll use two properties:

1) $log(a * b) = log(a) + log(b)$

2) $log(a^b) = b * log(a)$

Now, where does the $\bar{x}$ come in? Well, $\bar{x}$ is the average value for x. In this solution, it's really a convenient way of rewriting the sum of x. For any series x, $\sum x = n * \bar{x}$.

Comment: You didn't mention the H_0 and H_1 component so I'm assuming you don't need help with that, but that's where the calculus that @whuber mentioned comes in